# Splash Activity Classnotfoundexception only in api>20 level

Tags: android

My app only crashed in lower than 20 api level

**Error log**

```
E/Android Runtime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: docbooking.armino.bill_app_demo_24bit_static, PID: 1935
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{docbooking.armino.bill_app_demo_24bit_static/docbooking.armino.bill_app_demo.Splash_Screen}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "docbooking.armino.bill_app_demo.Splash_Screen" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/docbooking.armino.bill_app_demo_24bit_static-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/docbooking.armino.bill_app_demo_24bit_static-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
```

app running in 19<  versions.

Comment: Please, post your app level gradle file

Comment: are you using any libraries in your app

Comment: yes.../compile 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:4.1.0'//File explore.
    compile 'com.faendir:acra:4.10.0'//Error report.
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'//For Deleting fi

Comment: this are the libraries

Comment: @Diljith ok, check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are having **different versions** of **android support library** in your project and the library, check the version in your `library's gradle` file and add the same version to your `app's gradle` as well. This should solve the problem

or you could try adding this in your project's build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
```

Comment: but in my project compileSdkVersion is 26

Comment: try setting it as 24 or else you will have to add a different version of your library @Diljith

Comment: @ヅ fix I had solve that problem sir, I think its not perfect way... In program one class extent application super class. I done its for crash reporting via mail by user. I think its not supported by KitKat version.. so I commented that class access from manifest

Comment: @Diljith well if you are removing the library, its not a perfect solution i think